# CreateContainerError with microk8s, ghrc.io image

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, microk8s

The error message is **CreateContainerError**

```
Error: failed to create containerd container: error unpacking image: failed to extract layer sha256:b9b5285004b8a3: failed to get stream processor for application/vnd.in-toto+json: no processor for media-type: unknown
```

Image pull was successful with the token I supplied (jmtoken)

I am testing on AWS EC2 t2.medium, the docker image is tested on local machine.

Anybody experience this issue ? How did you solve it ?

deployment yaml file

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in my yaml file.

I supply `command` and `CMD` in K8S and Dockerfile each. So the `CMD` in Dockerfile which is actual command doesn't run, and cause side effects including this issue.

Another tip. Adding `sleep 3000` command in K8S sometimes solve other issues like crash.